# Error configuring PHP and MySQL installed from source

Tags: 12.04, mysql, php

I'm using ubuntu 12.04. the system requires `php5.2` and `mysql5.1`. I installed php and mysql from source. I encountered the following problem while configuring php:

```
./configure \
 --prefix=/usr/share/php52 \
 --with-apxs2=/usr/local/apache2/bin/apxs \
 --enable-mbstring \
 --with-curl \
 --with-mysql \
 --enable-embedded-mysqli \
 --enable-exif \
 --with-mcrypt 

checking for MSSQL support via FreeTDS... no
checking for MySQL support... yes
checking for specified location of the MySQL UNIX socket... no
checking for MySQL UNIX socket location... /tmp/mysql.sock
configure: error: Cannot find MySQL header files under yes.
Note that the MySQL client library is not bundled anymore!
```

What should I do?

Thanks in advance

Comment: look here http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?t=9636

Comment: @Olcay Ertaş In the future, please post the answer here with a link for reference or further information.

Answer (score 2):

From the above link:

> "apt-cache search mysql | grep dev" reveals that you need libmysqlclient15-dev.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to install from source. You can simply install tasksel via the terminal with `sudo apt-get install tasksel` and then run `sudo tasksel` and choose the option to install LAMP. LAMP stands for Linux, Apache, MySQL and php. See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Tasksel